# ORACLE APEX 18 JET Chart Dynamic Series

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

I was using AnyChart for all my chart in Apex 5. Now that I upgraded to 18.2, AnyChart is now "legacy". So, I wanted to update my chart to use JET Chart.

My chart used "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query". My PL/SQL Function body build my query dynamicaly and my number of series displayed may varied. As I don't know how many series I will have, I'm not able to set my series in my chart.

Here's my PL/SQL Function Body:

```
DECLARE
  l_selected  APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
  l_sql       VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
BEGIN
  --
  -- Convert the colon separated string of values into a PL/SQL array 
  l_sql := l_sql || 'SELECT NULL       link  ';
  l_sql := l_sql || '      ,year_month label ';
  l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P16_SELECT_LIST);
  --
  -- Loop over array to insert department numbers and sysdate
  IF l_selected.count = 0 THEN
    l_sql := l_sql || '      ,NULL "no data" ';
  ELSE
    FOR i IN 1..l_selected.count LOOP
      l_sql := l_sql || ',MIN(DECODE(sqn, '''||l_selected(i)||''', srt_cnt, NULL)) "'||l_selected(i)|| CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(l_selected(i)), '^[[:digit:]]') THEN ' Sqn' ELSE NULL END||'"';
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  l_sql := l_sql || '  FROM flight_and_mmh t ';
  l_sql := l_sql || ' WHERE snapshot_fk = :P27_SNAPSHOT_LIST ';
  l_sql := l_sql || '   AND INSTR('':'' || :P16_SELECT_LIST || '':'' , '':'' || sqn || '':'') > 0 ';
  l_sql := l_sql || ' GROUP BY t.year_month ';
  l_sql := l_sql || ' ORDER BY t.year_month ';
  RETURN l_sql;
END;
```

[Column Mapping of my serie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKpKS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need to use dynamic sql for multiple series in apex nowadays.

1. In the series region select: series => Source => Region Source
2. Then put your sql query in the main region source code.
3. Back in the series => Column Maping, u need to choose the **VALUE**, the **LABEL** and the **SERIES NAME** with the respective columns of your query.